# How to conduct an inner join with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins

My QGIS (2.8.2) joins always result in an outer join.  How do I create an inner join with QGIS?

Comment: Please remove the downvote and the [duplicate].  The proposed "answer" does not address the question, it merely states how to do a join.  My question was quite specific, regarding inner joins versus outer joins.

Answer (score 1):

It's currently not possible to do an inner join in one step but you can afterwards filter out those features which were not joined based on the resulting `NULL` values.

Comment: Hmmm... which field(s) would I use to filter out the non-joined features?  For example, the join table could have a matching record, based on the join field, but

Comment: Sorry about the previous comment.  Here's how I now create an inner join (possible only with 2.10, I think...): In "Layer Properties > Joins > Add Vector Join > Choose which fields are joined" I click the join field, which is subsequently displayed in the output attribute table.  I then do an attribute selection for "target field = join field".  The resulting records represent the inner join.  Voila!

Comment: I have the same problem but my data is huge. So the join which is stored on memory needs to be converted to a virtual layer. QGis stops responding when this happens.

Comment: stu's method worked for me on a 2.5 gb gdb joined to a table with 17,000 records. thanks!